# jQuery conflict

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have a wordpress plugin lightbox2 and a news scroller on my page.

My head section looks like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="wp-content/themes/soundsright/menu.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='wp-includes/js/prototype.js?ver=1.6'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='wp-includes/js/scriptaculous/wp-scriptaculous.js?ver=1.8.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='wp-includes/js/scriptaculous/effects.js?ver=1.8.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='wp-content/plugins/lightbox-2/lightbox.js?ver=1.8'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.3.2'></script>

    <!-- begin lightbox scripts -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="wp-content/plugins/lightbox-2/Themes/Grey/lightbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />');
    //]]>
    </script>
    <!-- end lightbox scripts -->


        <!-- SwfObj Plugin version SWFOBJ_VERSION -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="wp-content/plugins/swfobj/swfobject.js"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="wp-content/themes/soundsright/liscroll.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
   $("ul#ticker01").liScroll({travelocity: 0.03});  

});

</script>
```

As it is now, the news scroller works but not the lightbox plugin.
When I remove

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

then the lightbox works but not the news scroller.

I thought removing this jQuery refrence would have solved the problem cause wordpress already loads the same version of jQuery in this line

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.3.2'></script>
```

**Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?**

Answer (score 1):

I think this will be because of the `function()` clashing, we had something similar recently; you need to more precisely match it to jQuery (basically the $ reference will be owned by prototype or one of the other javascripts so you replace it with jQuery) e.g.

```
jQuery(function(){

   jQuery("ul#ticker01").liScroll({travelocity: 0.03});  

});
```

Comment: and obviously like you pointed out its not wise to load jQuery twice. (my tweak of the function above assumes that is the one meant to use jQuery and not any lightbox ones from your other javascript references for example).

Answer (score 0):

$ is used by both Prototype and jQuery:

http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

Answer (score 0):

Since both JQuery and Prototype use $ sign, use Jquery in non conflict mode

```
   jQuery.noConflict();

   JQuery(function(){
       JQuery("ul#ticker01").liScroll({travelocity: 0.03});      
   });
```

and use $ for Prototype